# Alt +f11 doesnt working in Microsoft Access 2016

Tags: ms-access-2016

Why in Access 2016, Alt+F11 shorcut wont switch from front end to VBA window?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Nvidia Geforce Experience installed...

1. Go to shortcut settings
2. Mark Alt+F11 assigned shorcut
3. Press Backspace to un-assign(delete) shortcut

[image: Geforce Experience keyboard shortcuts]

Thats it!